# Привязка к железу

Tags: c#, авторские-права, защита

На просторах сети немало устаревших и критикуемых кодерами (опять же, в смысле реализации защиты приложения) способов привязать использование программы к конкретной машине при помощи проверки информации вроде серийника HDD, процессора, материнской платы и т.д.
Какой же способ является наиболее надёжным и современным? Интересна реализация на C#.

Comment: Привязывайтесь к диску.

Comment: Я делал привязку к нескольким параметрам (HDD + мат.плата + версия ОС + ...). Не знаю на сколько это правильно и надежно, но для моих целей вполне хватило

Comment: @Donil, а откуда Вам это известно? 

Что, десятки взломщиков подняли лапки и с признанием своей криворукости прибежали покупать программу?

Или цель весьма прозаична - запудрить заказчику программы мозги, убедить его, что продукт реально ценный и при этом не ломается?

Comment: Конечно же второе:)

Comment: Настоящая защита может быть лишь в случае, если программа выполняется как сервис на сервере, и недоступна клиенту физически. Всё, что бежит на процессоре клиента, может быть взломано, так как система полностью под контролем клиента, и то, что может сделать его процессор, может сделать и его отладчик.
Поэтому да, вся "защита от копирования" — выбивание бабок из неграмотного заказчика.

Comment: Есть еще кое-какой надежный вариант - это привязка к "ключу", тот который подключается к USB входу и выглядит как флэшка, но она с контроллером. Тоже можно сказать является "железом". Не знаю как оно правильно называется, но все современные платные программы для компьютерной диагностики/чиптюнинга автомобилей идут именно с такими ключами.

Comment: Это так и называется - аппаратный ключ. И ломается он точно так же, как и любой другой, путём патча проверки валидности в проверяющей программе. Другое дело что софт, защищённый такими ключами, уже скорей индустриальных и промышленных масштабов, и на его взлом мало кто идёт :)

Comment: Сериализовать привязку к железу — это для того чтобы идентифицировать клиента.

А защиты платной версии от пролома — для каждой редакции (для каждого клиента) делай отдельный билд, да так, чтоб адресация менялась. Это достигается путем переписывания метода проверки ключа, к примеру.

Answer (score 9):

1. **C# без проблем декомпилируется в исходный код**. Поэтому попытки привязать всякие механизмы защиты - бессмысленная затея. Пустая трата времени и денег.
2. Лучше сделайте хороший продукт, и напишите лицензионное соглашение.
3. Можете добавить автоапдейтер, который при поиске обновлений, будет отправлять серийник к вам в компанию, где будет проверяться на валидность. Если он у вас зарегистрирован - молча отдаем обновления, если нет - ругаемся клиенту, и прекращаем выполнение программы, попутно где нибудь в реестре сохраняем инфу о невалидности программы. Но это тоже не панацея(см. п. 1).

Comment: > C# без проблем декомпилируется в исходный код

Не без проблем и не в исходный код (даже компиляция .net сборок происходит "с потерями"), но декомпилируется.

Comment: Окей, какие проблемы могут быть? И что именно теряется?

Comment: @nolka: ну, из очевидного теряются комментарии, имена локальных переменных и форматирование; куски, выброшенные препроцессором, и не реализованные partial-методы тоже восстановить, судя по всему, невозможно; лямбды превращаются в методы или во вспомогательные классы, генераторы и async/await разворачиваются в state-машину. Умный декомпилятор, вроде ILSpy/Reflector, часто может это всё свернуть назад.

Comment: @VlaD, комментарии - не смертельно, а все остальное - всего лишь препятствия, которые можно преодолеть. В крайнем случае, никто не мешает написать свой аналог взламываемой программы)

Comment: @nolka: вы правы, я лишь ответил на вопрос, в чём потери при компиляции.

Comment: Ну на самом деле все зависит от продукта и степеней защиты. Если его цена будет ниже цены взлома, то вряд ли кто то будет заниматься взломом. Если взломать будет дешевле, чем купить, тогда точно взломают. Мое мнение, не продавать дороже, а брать количеством продаж. Никакой 100% защиты не существует. А для халявщиков обновления тоже должны устанавливаться, причем без предупреждения, но скачиваться с другой папки, с некорректно работающими функциями, некоторыми ошибками, перегрузкой процессора, например. А на крайний случай вообще с каким нибудь вирусом...

Comment: krupennikov, тут уже пересекается грань этики  и даже закона:)
Вообще была идея, зашифровать искодный код в файл, во время выполнения компилить, а расшифровку делать через dll, Сшные куски распороть сложнее

Comment: @krupennikov, а порча информации (я уже не говорю о вирусах) это просто противозаконное деяние.

Кстати, ответные действия обиженных людей тоже не всегда укладываются в рамки официального законодательства.

Comment: Ни о какой порчи сторонней информации речь не идет. Услышали слово "Вирус" и сразу о порче! Если я напишу свою платную программу и ей будут пользоваться халявщики, то естественно для таких при необходимости могу написать вирус, находящийся в теле моей программы, который будет портить файлы/БД именно моей программы. И пусть потом предъявляют мне о нарушении закона за незаконное использование моей программы, в лицензионном соглашении которой будет указано о возможной потери данных нелицензионной продукции. На самом деле конечно это я делать вряд буду, но как крайнюю меру можно рассматривать.

Comment: Вот пример игры "Космические рейнджеры HD: Революция". В сети уже появились пиратские версии, взломанные. Но если играть, то сильно жарит солнце отнимая быстро жизнь, куча метеоритов в некоторых местах, еще какие нибудь баги. С лицензионной такой проблемы нет. А искать кучу багов и причину их проявления гораздо сложнее, чем вписать несколько нопов в джампы для запуска программы без лицензии.

Comment: @krupennikov, всё так, но вопрос только в затратах на такую защиту. Если они будут покрываться - да на здоровье :) Вот только сдаётся мне, что люди, имеющие дело с такими продажами, не задают подобные вопросы на хэшкоде, а просто нанимают специалистов - и по расчётно-финансовой части, и по технической :)

>Вот пример игры "Космические рейнджеры HD: Революция"

А был ещё редактор W&D - не помню уже точно, но где-то на пятой или шестой антиотладочной ловушке я сломался :)

Comment: В нашей стране, с развитым пиратством, люди, имеющие дело с такими продажами, задают чуть ли не главный вопрос о защите продукции специалистам. А вот специалисты (или начинающие специалисты) задают этот вопрос на хэшкоде. Ну это сугубо мое мнение :)

Comment: Специалист - он на то и специалист, чтобы знать ответы на вопросы по своей тематике. Во всяком случае я бы не взял на работу такого "специалиста".

Comment: @krupennikov: отношение к вирусам в программе зависит от общего настроя общества, в котором находятся ваши клиенты. Если вы при _каких угодно_ условиях намеренно разрушаете информацию на компьютере клиента, в Европе вашей фирме не будет никто доверять, и ваши продажи несомненно упадут.

---
Единственным цивилизованным методом противостояния незаконному копированию в Европе считается юридический. Программа, самостоятельно решающая, нарушил пользователь закон или нет, и "наказывающая" его, подпадает под категорию "самосуд", и оценивается соответственно.

Comment: @krupennikov, идея-то хорошая. Только как гарантировать, что такой механизм защиты сам по себе будет работать идеально, чтобы "под раздачу" не попали ни в чём не повинные честные пользователи?

Answer (score 2):

Складываете несколько параметров (материнка, жесткий и т.п.) в одну строку, и считаете md5 с солью.

Comment: Что в конечном итоге (как и куча всего остального) ломается забиванием несколькими нопами одного джампа :-)

Comment: либо пару бит поменять:)

Comment: Если защита чисто показная, то так - сойдет Ж)

Answer (score 2):

Может не совсем то, но все таки рискну написать.
В студенческие годы был на одном заводе, там была программка, которая была защищена с помощью [SenseLock](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SenseLock). По крайней мере мне это решение показалось очень интересным. И если я правильно понял, возможность исполнять программы, написанные на C, позволяют прописать любой механизм проверки (ограниченный количеством строк кода только).